# Count amount of users per login count per week

Tags: postgresql

I currently have an `accounts` table and an `account_activity` table. The relevant column for the `accounts` table is `id`. In the `account_activity` table, I have the columns `id`, `account_id`, `action_name` and `occured`.

I want to be able to plot a graph of how many users logged in 0 times, 1 time, 2 times, `n` times in a given timeframe (lets say `WHERE occured BETWEEN now() AND now() - interval '1 week'`)

I have gotten as far as selecting the amount of logins per user, using the following query:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    count(aa.*) AS logins
FROM
    account a
LEFT JOIN
    account_activity aa
ON
    a.id = aa.account_id AND
    aa.action_name = 'logIn'
GROUP BY
    a.id
```

This returns a list of `id`s and `logins` count. Now, I want to select every account that has a login count higher than `n` to be classed as `n`, so:

```
SELECT
    a.id,
    LEAST(count(aa.*), 10) AS logins
FROM
    account a
LEFT JOIN
    account_activity aa
ON
    a.id = aa.account_id AND
    aa.action_name = 'logIn'
GROUP BY
    a.id
```

In this case, `logins` will never be higher than `n` (10 in the query). Exactly the way I want it. But the result now requires me to manually loop over all rows, insert them into a temporary object and increment the count on each key from `0` to `n` where `row['logins'] == key`

I'd like to get a result like this:

```
| logins | count |
|--------|-------|
|      0 |    10 |
|      1 |   130 |
|      2 |    14 |
|    ... |   ... |
|      n |  1830 |
```

I have no clue how I'd be able to do this in PgSQL

Comment: I have read this 3 times and can't get past the _how many users logged in 0 times, 1 time, 2 times, n times in a given timeframe_ requirement. Is there something else in the requirement?

Comment: I want to be able to see how many of my users are active. If someone logged in 10 times within the last week, that person is very active. If someone hasn't logged in at all this week, that person is inactive.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I understand from the question:

```
select logins, count(*) as users
from (
    select count(*) as logins
    from account_activity aa
    where action_name = 'logIn'
    group by account_id
)
group by logins
order by logins
```

Comment: You're going to miss accounts with 0 logins.

Answer (score 0):

```
SElECT q2.logins as logins, count(*) AS num_users FROM
(
    SELECT sq.account_id AS account_id, sum(sq.login_count) AS logins FROM (
        (SELECT account_id, 1 AS login_count FROM
            account_activity WHERE action_name = 'login')
        UNION ALL
        (SELECT id AS account_id, 0 AS login_count FROM accounts)
    ) AS sq
    GROUP BY account_id
) AS q2
GROUP BY q2.logins;
```